# Listview with custom adapter won't work inside a SherlockFragment

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Adapter:

```
public class ServerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Server>
{
    private Context Context; 
    private int ResourceId;    
    private List<Server> Data = null;

    public ServerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Server> data)
    {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        ResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        Context = context;
        Data = data;
    }

    public void updateServersList(List<Server> newlist)
    {
        Data.clear();
        Data = newlist;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View Row = convertView;
        ViewHolder Holder = null;
        Server server = Data.get(position);
        if(Row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)Context).getLayoutInflater();
            Row = inflater.inflate(ResourceId, parent, false);

            Holder = new ViewHolder();          
            Holder.Hostname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hostname);
            Holder.Address = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            Holder.Players = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.players);
            Holder.Photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);   
            Row.setTag(Holder);
        }
        else
        {           
            Holder = (ViewHolder) Row.getTag();
        }

        Holder.Hostname.setText(server.getHostname());
        Holder.Address.setText("Address: " + server.getIp() + ":" + server.getPort());
        Holder.Players.setText("Players: " + server.getPlayers() + "/" + server.getMaxPlayers());
        Holder.Photo.setImageResource(server.getGameObject().getImageResId());
        return Row;
    }
}

class ViewHolder
{
   TextView Hostname;
   TextView Address;
   TextView Players;
   ImageView Photo;
}
```

SherlockFragment:

```
public class Favourites extends SherlockFragment
{   
    public static ListView FavoritesListView;
    public static ServerAdapter FavoritesAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.servers, null);

        FavoritesListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.serverlistview);
        FavoritesAdapter = new ServerAdapter(this.getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.server, DataHandler.getUserFavoriteServersFromLocal());        
        FavoritesListView.setAdapter(FavoritesAdapter);
        return v;
    }
}
```

servers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/serverlistview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>
```

server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/game"
            android:src="@drawable/game" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"   
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hostname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/hostname"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/address" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/players"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/address"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/address"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/players" />       
</RelativeLayout>
```

Errors:

> 07-30 13:11:38.824: E/AndroidRuntime(31423): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-30 13:11:38.824: E/AndroidRuntime(31423):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 07-30 13:11:38.824:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31423):  at
>   com.example.app.ServerAdapter.getView(ServerAdapter.java:47)
>   07-30 13:11:38.824: E/AndroidRuntime(31423):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159) 07-30
>   13:11:38.824: E/AndroidRuntime(31423):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
>   ...

Comment: Which line is 47 in `ServerAdapter.java`?

Comment: Holder.Hostname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hostname);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the way the fragment lifecycle works. In your onCreateView implementation, you make reference to the fragment's activity when creating the adapter. The problem is that the activity isn't made available to the fragment until onActivityCreated is called.

If you look at the [fragment lifecycle as described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) you can see that onCreateView is followed by a call into onActivityCreated.

Try moving some code from onCreateView into onActivityCreated:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.servers, null);      
    FavoritesListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.serverlistview);
    return v;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);    

    FavoritesAdapter = new ServerAdapter(this.getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.servers, DataHandler.getUserFavoriteServersFromLocal());       
    FavoritesListView.setAdapter(FavoritesAdapter); 


}
```

Additionally, you appear to be using the wrong variable in your adapter's getView() code. You test if Row==null (which means convertView is also null) and then assign Row to be the value of the newly inflated view. However, you then attempt to find a subview from the convertView, which is still null.

Try editing your adapter's getView() method as below:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View Row = convertView;
    ViewHolder Holder = null;
    Server server = Data.get(position);
    if(Row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)Context).getLayoutInflater();
        Row = inflater.inflate(ResourceId, parent, false);

        Holder = new ViewHolder();          
        //Holder.Hostname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hostname);
        //Holder.Address = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        //Holder.Players = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.players);
        //Holder.Photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);   
        Holder.Hostname = (TextView)Row.findViewById(R.id.hostname);
        Holder.Address = (TextView)Row.findViewById(R.id.address);
        Holder.Players = (TextView)Row.findViewById(R.id.players);
        Holder.Photo = (ImageView)Row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
        Row.setTag(Holder);
    }
    //etc
  }
```

Comment: it still doesn't work...
Can it be a problem with my layout? I added the xml file on the first post

Comment: @user824963 I've updated my answer. ernestofndz, who answered before me is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Might be cuz you are inflating Row with the layout and then keep using convertView to get the reference to your objects? I don't know how's your layout, just a suggestion.

```
View Row = convertView;
...
Row = inflater.inflate(ResourceId, parent, false); 
...       
Holder.Hostname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hostname);
```